# how does the execute command run in java?

Tags: java

I got an execute command java like this:

```
java -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms8G -Xmx8G -XX:MetaspaceSize=2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4g -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=85 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=85 -cp config:./lib/protect.jar:./lib/*  Protect > data/logday.log 2>&1
```

I don't know what this's called so i called it `Execute Command`.
could anyone tell me about this?
I want to know its document and the affection of order running of `-cp config`.
If i change  the order of the `-cp config`, is there anything change? 
Thanks.

Comment: Learn about the command line in your OS.

Comment: Read the manpage for java.exe [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: thank a lot. The document is big help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Type Java in your command line ( if you are using windows) or man Java in the terminal (if you are using linux).

The order of -cp config dosen't matter, just keep these options together -

-cp config:./lib/protect.jar:./lib/*

This option set the classpath of required libraries to run the application.

Comment: The order of classpath matters, when you have multiple versions of a class file in multiple classpath entries. Not all projects are big enough to warrant the use of Maven or similar systems.

Comment: Yes order of file paths matters but the order of -cp option doesn't matter here.